# How to find AWS keypair public key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh

So, it seems a developer on our team deleted the public key for our `App-Production.pem` key in our `.ssh/authorized_keys`, so the default AWS Key Pair no longer works, breaking our deployment pipeline.

Where can I find the public key to add back to `authorized_keys`? Is it possible to do this without having to boot a fresh instance?

Comment: Can you still login to that instance (eg with another keypair), or are you totally locked-out?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you have the private key, you can retrieve the public key.

If you are using Linux, use following command,

```
ssh-keygen -y
```

Then provide your path to private key file when prompted.
After that you will be given a public key. Save it.

Then use following steps to regain access to this instance.

- Stop your instance
- Detach root volume
- Attach volume to another instance as a data volume
- Modify the `authorized_keys` file with the public key
- Detach the data volume
- Re attach the volume to the affected instance

For more information [follow this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair).

Answer (score 3):

You can use this command to retrieve the public key for a given key-pair using key pair name:

```
aws ec2 describe-key-pairs --key-names <key-pair-name here> --include-public-key
```

or  using key pair id,

```
aws ec2 describe-key-pairs --key-pair-ids <key pair id here> --include-public-key
```

Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/describe-keys.html